# Distributed Database Design For Spring Boot Micro Services- Managing blurriness of Data Model between Micro Services

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, data-modeling, spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud

I am creating 4 separate micro services using spring cloud.

1. OAuth-2 Authenticating service
2. Resource Service
3. UI Service
4. Gateway Service

But my data model is `blurred` between these services. For example,

I have the domain models,

1. User
2. Group

User and Group have a *many to many* relationship

which I am intending to keep within **OAuth-2 Authenticating service**, hopefully in a separate database. and I have the following domain models,

1. Document

and this document should have a many to many relationship with the Group. I am hoping to keep this domain model in **Resources Service** again within a separate database.

Since these micro services have their `separate` data repositories, I am confused of how to provide a user interface so that a user can create new **Users**, create new **Groups** create new **Documents**, and assign users to **Groups** and also assign **Documents** to the **Groups**.

I am hoping to expose the Web View for this from the UI service. But I am confused of how to make use of the disinterestedness of micro services while adhering to a monolithic like data model.

Comment: The question isn't really specific to spring-boot or spring-cloud is it?

Comment: @spencergibb I was hoping that spring people will catch this up. There is a huge thing in spring boot, convention over configuration right. So, I think bootstrap matters?

Comment: I think your question is valid, but not specifically to spring. This could be written in go and your question is fine. Unfortunately, for me, I'd need a lot more information than you have given me, from the structure of your organization, to how clients interact with this system, service level agreements, better understanding of your data model, etc... Have you read http://www.amazon.com/Domain-Driven-Design-Tackling-Complexity-Software/dp/0321125215 ?